# How to reset file input form after uploading the image in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ng2-file-upload

We have 2 issues connected with selecting files and uploading it. The first issue is that when you upload an image the file name is still staying in the input. Here is the code.

```
OnFileSelected(event) {
    const file: File = event[0];

    this.ReadAsBase64(file)
      .then(result => {
        this.selectedFile = result;
      })
      .catch (err => this.error = err);

  }

  Upload() {
    if (this.selectedFile) {
      this.usersService.AddImage(this.selectedFile).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.socket.emit('refresh', {});
          console.log(data);
          this.SettingsForm.reset()
        },
        err => err
      );
    }
  }
  ReadAsBase64(file): Promise<any> {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const fileValue = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const result = reader.result;
        if (!result) reject('Cannot read variable');
        if (this.images.length>=4) reject('You can have only 4 images');
        if (result.length * 2  > 2**21) reject('File exceeds the maximum size'); // Note: 2*2**20 = 2**21 
        resolve(reader.result);
      });

      reader.addEventListener('error', event => {
        reject(event);
      });

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });

    return fileValue;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Example file input</label>
                    <input #myInput ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" (onFileSelected)="OnFileSelected($event)" type="file"
                        class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" />
                </div>
                <p *ngIf="error"> {{error}}</p>
                <button (click)="Upload()" type="submit" class=" btn btn-default submit-btn btn-upload ">
                    <i class="material-icons">attachment</i>
                    Upload Image</button>
            </div>
```

How to reset the form after uploading the image?
Also, how can I make the error message shown for 3 seconds for example? If you select the wrong file error stays there all the time even after adding the valid file. We thought about adding

```
setTimeout(() => {

        }, 3000); // just example
      },
```

but not sure where to add it? How can I fix these 2 issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this
in your `component.ts`

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Then defining a variable to hold it:

```
@ViewChild('myInput')
myInputVariable: ElementRef;
```

Then in your function

```
Upload() {
    if (this.selectedFile) {
      this.usersService.AddImage(this.selectedFile).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.socket.emit('refresh', {});
          console.log(data);
          this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.value = "";
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

To remove the error:
OnFileSelected(event) {
    const file: File = event[0];

```
this.ReadAsBase64(file)
  .then(result => {
    this.selectedFile = result;
  })
  .catch (err => {this.error = err; setTimeout(()=> {this.error = ''},2000}));
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about error message timeout? Is there any way to remove the error message after 3s for example?

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: Time out is not working. I think something should be changed in OnFileSelected(event) not in upload one.

Comment: The obstacle is then .catch for a timeout that is why I asked it.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more as your problem isn't clear

Comment: Perfect, +1 as it works for me. i am using angular 8, so static: true was required in @ViewChild ("uploadedFileId", {static: true}) myInputVariable: ElementRef;

Comment: this didn't work for me, I'm working with angular 7

Comment: Reason could be anything best will be to post another question you can tag me with example